# .htaccess to redirect to folder after ignoring the extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

My requirement is the URL should be redirected as mentioned below

http://mysite.com/page1.html   ==> http://mysite.com/page1
http://mysite.com/page2.html   ==> http://mysite.com/page2

In the above example page1/page2 are folders in root which should be redirected from the page1.html or page2.html.

Can anyone please give the solution or enhancements to the following solution.

I am trying to use the following syntax.

```
Redirect permanent http://mysite.com/page1.html http://mysite.com/page1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use THE_REQUEST variable.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.html[^\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
```